# Recursive data type like a tree as Avro schema

Tags: protocols, avro, recursive-datastructures

Reading https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html it says a schema must be one of:

- A JSON string, naming a defined type.
- A JSON object, of the form:
  `{"type": "typeName" ...attributes...}` where `typeName` is either a
  primitive or derived type name, as defined below. Attributes not
  defined in this document are permitted as metadata, but must not
  affect the format of serialized data.
- A JSON array, representing a
  union of embedded types.

I want a schema that describes a tree, using the recursive definition that a tree is either:

- A node with a value (say, integer) and a list of trees (the children)
- A leaf with a value

My initial attempt looked like:

```
{
  "name": "Tree",
  "type": [
    {
      "name": "Node",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "value",
          "type": "long"
        },
        {
          "name": "children",
          "type": { "type": "array", "items": "Tree" }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Leaf",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "value",
          "type": "long"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But the Avro compiler rejects this, complaining there is nothing of type `{"name":"Tree","type":[{"name":"Node"...`. It seems Avro doesn't like the union type at the top-level. I'm guessing this falls under the aforementioned rule "a schema must be one of .. a JSON object .. where typeName is either a primitive or derived type name." I am not sure what a "derived type name" is though. At first I thought it was the same as a "complex type" but that includes union types..

Anyways, changing it to the more convoluted definition:

```
{
  "name": "Tree",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [{
    "name": "ctors",
    "type": [
      {
        "name": "Node",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "value",
            "type": "long"
          },
          {
            "name": "children",
            "type": { "type": "array", "items": "Tree" }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Leaf",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "value",
            "type": "long"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

works, but now I have this weird record with just a single field whose sole purpose is to let me define the top-level union type I want.

Is this the only way to get what I want in Avro or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

While this is not an answer to the actual question about representing a recursive named union (which isn't possible as of late 2022), it is possible to work around this for a tree-like data structure.

If you represent a `Tree` as a node, and a `Leaf` as a node with an empty list of children, then one recursive type is sufficient:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "TreeNode",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "value",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "children",
      "type": { "type": "array", "items": "TreeNode" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, your three types `Tree`, `Node`, and `Leaf` are unified into one type `TreeNode`, and there is no union of `Node` and `Leaf` necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled uppon the same problem wanting to define a recursive union. I'm quite pessimistic about a cleaner solution than your convoluted one, because there is currently no way to name an union, and hence no way to recursively refer to it while constructing it, see this [open ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-248)