# Create n-ary tree using Avro Schema

Tags: avro

I need to define a schema in `.avsc` file which will be compiled using a maven plugin, to create classes.

The class has to be a tree, where root is of different type, and all nodes are of another type.

For example:

```
(Root) -> (Node A) -> (Node C) -> (Node F)
              -    -> (Node D)
              -    -> (Node E)
   -   -> (Node B) -> (Node F)
```

To follow this structure, classes will need to follow:

```
class Node {
    String id;
    String name;
    ArrayList<Node> children;
}

class Root {
    ArrayList<Node> children;
}
```

I understand that I can simply extend `SpecificRecordBase` to make my class follow the structure of other `Record` classes that I got generated using the same plugin, and avro schemas; but is there a way to create such structures using avro schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
    {
"namespace": "com.tree.yournamespace",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "TreeRoot",
 "fields": [
      {
      "name": "nodes", "type": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                      "name": "Node",
                      "type": "record",
                      "fields": [
                           {"name": "children", "type": {
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": "Node"
                                }
                           }
                      ]
                  }
              }
       }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Pasting this into https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/avro.jsp results in "message" : "illegal Avro schema", "exceptionClass": org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException", "exceptionMessage" : "Can't redefine: com.tree.yournamespace.Node", "info" : "other messages follow (if any)"
} ].  The answer found here worked for me though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839454/recursive-data-type-like-a-tree-as-avro-schema

Comment: Yes my bad, declared Node twice, first one should be "Root"... Fixed. Thanks.